# How can I fix sentences detection in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, sentences

I wanted to use hl-sentences module and discovered in the process that the sentence detection, and thus move between sentence is buggy inside org-mode.

```
* Title

some text:

- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3

** sub-title
```

If I do an `org-forward-sentence`  when my cursor is positioned in the second bullet for instance. I'm jumping to the end of `sub-title`.

Worse if I do a `org-backward-sentence` when I'm in the middle of `bullet 2`, the first time I'm going back to the beginning (the `b`) of `bullet 2` (which is ok) but if I do another `org-backward-sentence` I'm jumping back to the start of `some text:`.

This feel very wrong as by intuition I would imagine that `org-backward-sentence` should be a projection.

I would prefer that org-mode treat each bullet as a single sentence.
And also that starting a new "heading" means the end of any previous sentence.

So perhaps there are good reason for these behaviour if not I would appreciate a pointer on how to fix that problem. Perhaps even propose a PR to org-mode.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that org-mode uses `org-forward-paragraph` as replacement for `forward-paragraph` but `forward-paragraph` is still used in elisp functions.

For an instance `forward-sentence` directly uses `forward-paragraph` and `org-forward-sentence` directly uses `forward-sentence`.

A hacky solution is to override `forward-paragraph` with `org-forward-paragraph` in an advice of `forward-sentence`:

```el
(defun forward-sentence-with-org-forward-paragraph (oldfun &rest args)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            (advice-add #'forward-paragraph :override (lambda (&optional _arg) (org-forward-paragraph)) '((name . "org-forward-paragraph")))
            (apply oldfun args))
        (advice-remove #'forward-paragraph "org-forward-paragraph"))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(with-current-buffer "test.org"
  (advice-add #'forward-sentence :around #'forward-sentence-with-org-forward-paragraph))
```

The general solution would be to avoid `forward-sentence` in `org-forward-sentence` and to use `org-forward-paragraph` in `org-forward-sentence`. But that is quite a bit of work...

Answer (score 0):

[emacs-sentence-navigation.el](https://github.com/noctuid/emacs-sentence-navigation) is dedicated to **sentence navigation**, and will help in most cases... but not in yours, because it lacks "standard" sentences (capitalized word following a period). If your bullets contained "real" sentences, this package would detect them.